# How to perform returns on table (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am wondering if you can help with this Matlab programming issue.
I have a table similar to this:

```
            31/01/2023    01/02/2023    02/02/2023     03/02/2023 
02/01/2023   202,00     228,5   219 198
03/01/2023   195,00     215     206 206
04/01/2023   182,00     196     191 185
05/01/2023   185,00     202     200 198
06/01/2023   184,00     206     200 198
07/01/2023   182,00     207     207 199
08/01/2023   180,00     199     195 192
09/01/2023   179,00     192     189 184
```

I would like to compute returns for each column, so that (195/202), (182/195), (185/182)... so basically for each column the value of the row / the value of the row-1.

Could you help me?

I have tried this code in Matlab but does not work (name of the table is "ret_table").

```
for col = 2:size(ret_table, 2)
    for row = 2:size(ret_table, 2)
        current_value = ret_table{row, col};
        previous_value = ret_table{row-1, col};
            if isnumeric(current_value) && isnumeric(previous_value)
                ret_table{row, col} = (current_value / previous_value);
            end
    end
end
```

It would become something like this:

```
           31/01/2023   01/02/2023  02/02/2023  03/02/2023
02/01/2023  NaN NaN NaN NaN
03/01/2023  -0,04   -0,06   -0,06    0,04 
04/01/2023  -0,07   -0,09   -0,08   -0,11 
05/01/2023   0,02    0,03    0,05    0,07 
06/01/2023  -0,01    0,02    -       -   
07/01/2023  -0,01    0,00    0,03    0,01 
08/01/2023  -0,01   -0,04   -0,06   -0,04 
09/01/2023  -0,01   -0,04   -0,03   -0,04
```

But I keep getting this error: Error using  /
Arguments must be numeric, char, or logical.

and if I use "./" :
Error using  ./
Both inputs must have the same row labels.

Edit: I have solved it by doing this way:

```
    ret_table = array2table(PUN_fwd);

for col = 2:size(ret_table, 2)
    for row = 2:size(ret_table, 1) 
        current_value = table2array(ret_table{row, col});
        previous_value = table2array(ret_table{row-1, col});
        Returns{row, col} = log1p(current_value / previous_value);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things are worth noting in your code.

The first is that on line `row = 2:size(ret_table, 2)` you should loop on dimension 1 and not 2 to move through all the rows, meaning ´row = 2:size(ret_table, 1)´. Looping on 2 will work satisfactory only if you have a square table, which is not a safe assumption.

Second, you don't get the expected results because on line `ret_table{row, col} = (current_value / previous_value);` you modify the table itself at every loop. So every time you are not using the original `ret_table` element but the calculation made of it at the prior iteration. The solution to this is to create a copy of the table and, while parsing the original, changing the copy (see comments in code).

```
ret_table_cpy=ret_table; %create copy
for col = 2:size(ret_table, 2)
    for row = 2:size(ret_table, 1) %loops using rows
        current_value = ret_table{row, col};
        previous_value = ret_table{row-1, col};
            if isnumeric(current_value) && isnumeric(previous_value)
                ret_table_cpy{row, col} = (current_value / previous_value); %edit copy
            end
    end
end

ret_table=ret_table_cpy; %reassign to original
clear ret_table_cpy %delete copy
```

This will get the following result:

```
02/01/2023        202      228.5        219        198
03/01/2023    0.96535    0.94092    0.94064     1.0404
04/01/2023    0.93333    0.91163    0.92718    0.89806
05/01/2023     1.0165     1.0306     1.0471     1.0703
06/01/2023    0.99459     1.0198          1          1
07/01/2023    0.98913     1.0049      1.035     1.0051
08/01/2023    0.98901    0.96135    0.94203    0.96482
09/01/2023    0.99444    0.96482    0.96923    0.95833
```

At last, you need to establish a rule for the first row because clearly the operation cannot be performed there since there is no precedent element to use.

Comment: Unfortunately it gets the same error, as:
>> ret_table_cpy{row, col} = (current_value / previous_value)
Error using  / 
Arguments must be numeric, char, or logical.

Comment: it was not mentioned in the question, i thought you were just getting wrong results, not errors. Update the question accordingly.

Comment: anyways if i were to guess it is because of how you imported the table from your CSV. The first column will be imported as a cell instead of a double because you use ',' instead of '.' for decimals in the file. Just import it as it is and cast the column to double with `ret_table{:,2}=str2double(ret_table{:,2})`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by doing this way:

```
    ret_table = array2table(PUN_fwd);

for col = 2:size(ret_table, 2)
    for row = 2:size(ret_table, 1) 
        current_value = table2array(ret_table{row, col});
        previous_value = table2array(ret_table{row-1, col});
        Returns{row, col} = log1p(current_value / previous_value);
    end
end
```